# way to get system_identifier from files in data directory on disk

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

**Context**

Using postgresql, I would like a way to make sure that the server I am talking with over a pgsql connection is the one that serves a specific `/path/to/data/` directory on the local server.

I know there is a `system_identifier` value I an get from a `SELECT system_identifier FROM pg_control_system()` query on the server, I would like to compare this with a value read from files on disk.

The use case is [in wal-g](https://github.com/wal-g/wal-g) : for some reason, their delta backup algorithm has to access the postgres files on disk while running some actions through a connection with the server, and their way to check that both are coherent is to compare the `data/` path provided by the user with the `SHOW data_directory` read from the postgresql connection.
However, the paths may well match even if postgresql is hosted on a different server -- e.g: if the data path looks like `/data/postgresql/data`, it may very well exits on server1 *and* server2.

**Question**

- if `system_identifier` is the way to go : is there a documented, stable way to read it directly from files on disk ?
- is there another simple way to check that "the server I'm talking to on [ip:port]" is the one that serves `/path/to/data` from my local server ?

---

[edit] it turns out `system_dentifier` is not a value that identifies uniquely a server -- for example: our hot standby database has the same `system_identifier` as our main database. So `system_identifier` doesn't fit the bill for: identify one specific postgresql instance.

The answers to the "how do I get system_identifier from disk ?" part are correct.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The server that runs on a certain data directory can only be determined by running `SHOW data_directory;` and comparing the result. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: say you have several servers and containers which all store their databases in `/var/lib/pgsql/data`, comparing whether `[net connection] > show data_directory` with a local path won't do you any good, you could still be connected to the replication server, or another server ...  I'm looking for a way to identify with some level of confidence "the database on that file system is the same as the one served through that IP / port"

Comment: in our case, it is just a main server and a replica server, but given that wal-g is a generic tool, I was curious about how to establish "I'm connected to the correct database" with more certainty.

Comment: If you want to distinguish primary and standby, the system identifier won't help you, since it is the same. Your question still confused me. Why do you want to distinguish them? What is the actual objective or problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I'm looking at the code of a backup implementation, which uses the sequence `SELECT pg_backup_start()`, [copy files from `data/` directory], `SELECT pg_backup_stop()`. As a sanity check, they try to establish that the `data/` is actually the one served through the postgresql connection. At the moment : they check if the path to `data/` on disk is the same as what they see through the pgsql connection (`SHOW data_directory`). I just realized that, if you are comparing paths from two distinct file systems, this won't help you [...]

Comment: [...] so I was wondering what other information I could inspect that would indicate that the `data/` path I am currently copying is actually the one behind the server xto which I issue `pg_backup_start() / ..._stop()`. Since the backup from a hot standby should be correct, perhaps I do not need to distinguish between "primary" and "hot standby" after all. Would you agree to say : "if the `system_identifier` read from disk is the same as `SELECT system_identifier` from the pgsql connection, then I am backing up the correct data directory" ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, then checking the system identifier is a good idea. By the way, Jeff's answer is the better one. There is one thing you are missing: it could be that you ran `pg_backup_start()` on the standby and now try to backup the data directory of the primary or a different standby. I am sure that could lead to problems with race conditions when you recover, but I cannot prove it. Also, I don't know how you can easily protect yourself from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System identifier you retrieving using `SELECT system_identifier FROM pg_control_system();` is equal to first 8 bytes of `global/pg_control` file of your cluster.

```
[postgres@admin200 ~]$ psql -tc 'select to_hex(system_identifier) from pg_control_system();'
 634d08977b5aa882

[postgres@admin200 ~]$ head -c8 /var/lib/pgsql/15/data/global/pg_control | od -An -tx1
 82 a8 5a 7b 97 08 4d 63
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL comes with a binary for reading the control data.  I don't know if that binary will automatically be in your PATH or not, it would depend on your package manager and your installation method.

```
pg_controldata -D  /data/postgresql/data |fgrep 'Database system identifier'
```